# Reading in strings

Tags: c, string

I am asked to take a string and reverse it, but I'm not sure how to do it, so I tried simply reading in the string, and reprinting it out. But I am having trouble with that too. Could somebody point me in the right direction?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
  char* word[64];
  printf("Input: ");
  fgets(*word, 256, stdin);
  printf("Reversed: %s\n", *word);

  return 0;
} //end main
```

Comment: Why you are using `fscanf` here?

Comment: professor told me to.

Comment: But you are not dealing with **files**! Do you want to take input from user or from a file?

Comment: oh ok, never mind, im supposed to use fgets, but still having trouble.

Answer (score 2):

Change this

```
  char* word[64];
  printf("Input: ");
  fscanf(stdin, "%s", *word);
  printf("Reversed: %s\n", *word);
```

to

```
  char word[64]; // remove the "*" so it's a char array, not array of char*
  printf("Input: "); // no change
  fscanf(stdin, "%s", word); // remove the * so you point to the array
  printf("Reversed: %s\n", word); // print out the string
```

---

Your fgets version should be

```
  char word[64];
  printf("Input: ");
  fgets(word, 64, stdin);
  printf("Reversed: %s\n", word);
```

Comment: i thought strings were supposed to be two dimensional char arrays?

Comment: and also, what if i were to use fgets instead of fscanf?

Comment: No, char arrays are one dimensional. See above for fgets version.

Comment: *Strings* (plural) would be two-dimensional char arrays: one index per string, and one for each character in a string. Unless you want to handle multiple strings, you only need a single char array. "I am asked to take **a** string", that's one, right?

Comment: Don't forget that `fgets()` generally reads and retains the newline at the end of a line, unless the line is too long to fit in the space it is passed.  So, you'll need to remove the newline before reversing the string.

Answer (score -1):

To reverse the string, you can use **for**  and a **swap**

```
   for( i = 0 ; i < len/2 ; i++ )   
   {        
       tmp = s[i];
       s[i] = s[len-i];   
       s[len-] = tmp;         
   }
```

**len** is the length of the string, you can use function strlen to calculate.**tmp** is a temperary variable.

Comment: Does not answer the question.